# How can I fix my page rendering/refreshing issues with making a call to an API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, vite

I have a very small task here. I just need to visualize the data from the given API to a line chart and then just add some decent styling. I am in the beginning stages here and just trying to ensure that my app will work first before I start with making the chart. However, I face very weird issues before even getting to issues with the chart. Given the following code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
 const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {
   axios.get('https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=65.01&longitude=25.47&hourly=temperature_2m')
     .then(response => {
       setWeather(response.data);
       setLoading(false);
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.error(error);
       setLoading(false);
     });
 }, []);

 return (
   <div>
     {loading === true && !weather ? <p>Loading weather data from API. Please wait.</p> : null}
     <h1>Weather</h1>
     {console.log(weather)}
   </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

I can refresh the page as many times as I like and component always re-renders. However, after making even the smallest changes, such as:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=65.01&longitude=25.47&hourly=temperature_2m')
      .then(response => {
        setWeather(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  const hourlyTemperaturesOneWeek = weather.hourly.temperature_2m;
  const hoursOneWeek = weather.hourly.time;

  return (
    <div>
      {loading === true && !weather ? <p>Loading weather data from API. Please wait.</p> : null}
      <h1>Weather</h1>
      {weather ? (
        <div>
      <p>Temperatures: {hourlyTemperaturesOneWeek}</p>
      <p>Hours: {hoursOneWeek}</p>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This will be fine upon saving the file. However, upon page refresh, it breaks and I receive "weather.hourly" is undefined. In order for the page to work again at all, I must revert it to the previous code. This is very frustrating and I have searched online for the issue and tried a few solutions, but nothing has worked for my page. Any help would be highly appreciated. I'm hoping and thinking that it is something very simple that somebody would probably see in a flash. Asking AI also didn't result in anything useful. Thanks in advance for anybody that has a good solution :)

P.S. Not sure if it is worth mentioning, but I also used Vite for setup. In addition, I am wanting to use either Highcharts, Chart.js, or react-chartjs-2, but I am also open to other suggestions, if anybody has some.

Comment: `weather` is initialized as an array.  What do you *expect* `weather.hourly` to be and why?  When you update the `weather` state, what exact value are you updating it to?

Comment: `weather` should be a JSON object retrieved from the given API link because it will be a collection of different data about the weather (as can be seen if you do an API test the given link in Postman or here real quick: https://reqbin.com/ ). 

`weather.hourly.temperature_2m` and `weather.hourly.time` should each be a collection of 168 values, as they are hourly over an entire week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a comment above...

> weather should be a JSON object

Then (1) don't define it as an array, but instead as an object:

```
const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
```

Being consistent with your types will help you better understand the data you're using and avoid confusion like this.

Additionally, (2) don't assume data will be present if that data is fetched asynchronously.  You can use optional chaining to conditionally grab values from within the object:

```
const hourlyTemperaturesOneWeek = weather.hourly?.temperature_2m;
const hoursOneWeek = weather.hourly?.time;
```

In cases where the `hourly` property is `undefined` this will simply result in setting those `const` values to `null`, without producing an error.

Comment: I had tried both!....but not at the same time. Thanks so much. I accepted your answer. :)